# For which values of $a \in (0,\infty)$, is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac 1n -\arctan \left(\frac 1n\right)\right)^a$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which values of $a \in (0,\infty)$ , is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\dfrac 1n -\arctan \Big(\dfrac 1n\Big)\bigg)^a$ convergent ? I have noticed that $\arctan \dfrac 1n<\dfrac 1n , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ and so   have found that for $a>1$ , the series is convergent by comparing to the series $\sum\dfrac1{n^a}$ (limit comparison test ) . But what about $a<1$ ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to Taylor expand $\text{arctan}(x)-x$ at $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac1n-\arctan\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac{1}{n^3}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \arctan x}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - x + \frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^3)}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^{3}}{3}+ O(x^3)}{x^3} = \frac{1}{3}$$
thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\dfrac 1n -\arctan \Big(\dfrac 1n\Big)\bigg)^a < \infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3a}}  < \infty$$
but the second serie is much simpler to examine and you get that it converges if and only if
$$3a > 1 \iff a > \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac1n-\arctan\left(\frac1n\right)> 0$ for any $n\geq 1$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^3 \left(\frac1n-\arctan\left(\frac1n\right)\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\arctan x}{x^3} = \frac{1 -\frac1{1+x^2}}{3x^3} = \frac13.$$
Hence
$$\frac1n-\arctan\left(\frac1n\right)\sim \frac1{n^3}.$$
Using the comparison principle, the serie diverges iff $a \leq \frac13$ and converges iff $a > \frac13$.